# unable to store multiple sed operations using pipe in a variable

Tags: shell, unix

I am not able to execute a multiple sed statement using pipe filters in a variable. 
i am trying to extract a path from a file and then working on that path to change a few letters within the path by going through another sed statement.

the code looks like this:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
do
  for j in F E I D
  do
  cpath="`sed -n "11,11p" <path.cfg | sed -n 's/voicex/voice'$i'/g; s/voicecolx/voicecol'$i'/g; s/" F "/" '$j' "/g;P'`"
  echo $cpath
   more $cpath 2>error.log | grep " '&j' " | wc -l | echo "The count of '$j' in file is: " `wc -l` 1>countdir/count$j.txt
  done
done
```

i saved this file in stest.sh. When i run the file, nothing happens. I ahve to press Ctrl+C to exit back to the command prompt.

Let me also provide the path.cfg file:

```
MPAY
/var/xacct_data/xxxx/log_flattener/xxxx/logfile_current

FAFF
/var/xacct_data/faff/faff1/log_flattener/faffsnp1/ logfile_current
/var/xacct_data/faff/faff1/log_flattener/faffdbt1 /logfile_current
/var/xacct_data/faff/faff1/log_flattener/fafftxn1 /logfile_current
/var/xacct_data/faff/faff2/log_flattener/faffdbt2/ logfile_current

VOICE
/var/xacct_data/voice/voicex/log_flattener/ voicecolx/logfile_current
/var/xacct_data/voice/voicex/log_flattener/ voiceprox/logfile_current
/var/xacct_data/voice/voicex/log_flattener/ voicedisx/logfile_current

GPRS
/var/xacct_data/gprs/gprsx/log_flattener/gprscolx/logfile_current
/var/xacct_data/gprs/gprsx/log_flattener/gprsprox/logfile_current
/var/xacct_data/gprs/gprsx/log_flattener/gprsdisx/logfile_current

IPC
/var/xacct_data/ipc/ipcx/log_flattener/ipccolx/logfile_current
/var/xacct_data/ipc/ipcx/log_flattener/ipcprox/logfile_current
/var/xacct_data/ipc/ipcx/log_flattener/ipcdisx/logfile_current

SMS
/var/xacct_data/smsc/smscx/log_flattener/smsccolx/logfile_current
/var/xacct_data/smsc/smscx/log_flattener/smscprox/logfile_current
/var/xacct_data/smsc/smscx/log_flattener/smscdisx/logfile_current
```

Comment: please add a tag to indcate which shell you are using, bash/sh, ksh, dash, zsh? Good luck

Comment: When using _sed_ for path manipulation I find it easier to use another delimiter. For example `sed 's#voicex#voice#'`

Answer (score 0):

In order to get specific advice, you need to provide a sample `path.cfg`, explain what's wrong with the script current's behavior and what the expected behavior is. That being said, there are a few red flags in your code.

- Use `$(…)` instead of `` `…` `` for command substitutions. The parsing of backquotes is rather fiddly, and you may run into issues with nested quotes.
- `sed -n "11,11p"` means print the 11th line only. Is this what you really wanted? I guess not, but knowing neither the format of `path.cfg` nor what you intended I can't tell you what that command should be.
- You should always use double quotes around variable substitutions, e.g. `echo "$cpath"`. Only leave them out if you know it would be wrong to have them, do put them if you have no good reason to omit them. I don't think this is causing any problem here, but it's a good habit to get into when writing shell scripts.
- Why are you calling `more`? Piping `more` into another program is useless. Just write `<"$cpath" grep " '&j' " | …`, assuming you did want to display all the lines containing the string `'&F'` (and so on for other values of `$j`) in the file called `$cpath`.
- Still on this line, `grep PATTERN | wc -l` can just be written `grep -c PATTERN`.
- Still on this line, you're running `wc -l` on the output of `wc -l`, which isn't useful. I supposed you meant to run it only once. Here are two ways to write this line; the first is closed to your structure, the second is rather clearer:

  ```
  <"$cpath" grep -c " '&j' " | echo "The count of '$j' in file is:  $(cat)" >"countdir/count$j.txt"
  echo "The count of '$j' in file is:  $(<"$cpath" grep -c " '&j' ")" >"countdir/count$j.txt"
  ```

Comment: i tried running the statement you mentioned and the result is same. as soon as i execute the script, nothing happens and I have to press "Ctrl+C" to return to the prompt..

Comment: @amit: You tried to run what? Edit your question to show exactly what you ran, and provide all the necessary input files.

Comment: @amit: If the script seems to be blocking, it's probably because some command is reading from standard input, and you forgot a redirection so it's waiting for you to type something. There's no such problem in what you posted however, so I guess you haven't posted *exactly* what you ran. Until you do that, you're not going to get better help.

Comment: this is exactly what i have. there isnt an extra word in the script.